# InfoPath does not support customizing the form used for this list.

Tags: 2013, infopath, library

I have Used InfoPath form for SharePoint 2013 list.
and it works fine.

But now when I am trying to create InfoPath form for **Library** it shows error

**InfoPath does not support customizing the form used for this list.**

[image]

Can any one explain what is this ?

Comment: You can use InfoPath to create different forms for List entry and editing, but not for Libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use InfoPath to create different forms for List entry and editing, but not for Libraries.

You can view this thread for more details

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2009/12/17/customize-a-sharepoint-list-form-using-infopath-2010/#comments

Laura from InfoPath team commented on this

> We don’t support customizing document library forms in InfoPath. This error should not appear in the final released product.
>
> Laura Harrington (InfoPath Team)